# Can the 2-D Cavalieri Principle be used to derive the area of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, area

It is pretty obvious that the area of a circle is $kr^2$, can we prove that $k = \pi$ (half of the angles of the circumference) with 2-D Cavalieri principle?

The principle is this: given two figures delimited between two parallel lines, if all lines parallel to both original lines cut the two figures in equal segments, then the figures have the same area.

This problem popped in my head as a way to avoid explicitly teaching calculus to high schoolers

Comment: Cavalieri for a disk amounts to $A = 2\int_{-r}^{r} \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}\, dx$, which says the area of the disk is the area of a certain half-ellipse, which doesn't help here. <> Is Archimedes' method of exhaustion not suitable...?

Comment: Why not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_circle#/media/File:CircleArea.svg?